# Fractions for xtick labels in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to position and label some xticks, but I want some of the labels to be nicely typeset fractions. I can see that pyplot.xtick accepts text elements as labels, but I'm a little confused about how to somehow turn a LaTeX expression into such a label.

Here's a simplification of what I'd like to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xticks([1,2.5,4], ['1', '5/2', '4'])
plt.show()
```

It sure would be nice if that 5/2 looked like a $\frac{5}{2}$. I've spent close to an hour on this and am flummoxed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have, because `'$\frac{5}{2}$'` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    >>> from matplotlib import rc
    >>> import matplotlib.pylab as pl
    >>> rc('text',usetex=True)
    >>> pl.plot(range(5))
    >>> pl.xticks([1,2.5,4],[r'$1$',r'$\frac{5}{2}$',r'$4$'])
    >>> pl.show()
```